# parsing .obj 3D graphics file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing, 3d, .obj

I have a question. I know that its not possible to parse .obj 3D graphics file using JavaScript and we have to convert it into some other format (preferably JSON). But I want to know why? Why we can't parse .obj file using JavaScript?

I would really appreciate your comments and answers.

Thanks
Vik

Comment: The only real obstacle I see is presenting the data in 3D (which may not be something you need), and getting the file to the JavaScript client. But that can easily be done through a webservice etc or with the new HTML 5 JS File API.

Comment: You seay "I know its not possible ... but I want to know why?" ... it does not make sense. How can you say something is not possible, when you don't know why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure you can... why not?  It's a text file, just go ahead and parse it.

Here, I'll even get you started:

```
var objText = getObjFile();
var obj = {};
var vertexMatches = objText.match(/^v( -?\d+(\.\d+)?){3}$/gm);
if (vertexMatches)
{
    obj.vertices = vertexMatches.map(function(vertex)
    {
        var vertices = vertex.split(" ");
        vertices.shift();
        return vertices;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can. I have even written my own library for parsing 3D formats - [K3D.js](http://k3d.ivank.net). It also supports MD2, 3DS and Collada. OBJ was the easiest to code :)

Answer (score 0):

There are now a few Javascript libraries to read Wavefront OBJ files. This one works well, though only reads OBJ files and does not output them https://www.npmjs.com/package/obj-file-parser. You can also do this with three.js: https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/OBJLoader.